# Zoom extent OSM

Tags: openstreetmap, zoom, qgis-2.10

I have an older version of QGIS on my private computer where the zoom extent of OSM is much greater than the newer version (10.1 Pisa) on my work computer.

Is there any way of being able to zoom in on the OSM map to a greater extent without it disapearing on the new version of QGIS?

Comment: How do you get the OSM layer in QGIS ? (a plugin, which one ?, a raster file ...) Which version of QGIS are you using on your private computer ?

Answer (score 1):

The current version of the Openlayers plugin only works for scales up to about 1:2500.

If you want to get more, use the new `QuickMapServices` plugin, or the `TileLayer` Plugin. You  have to modify the configuration file of the second manually to get OpenStreetMap tiles. See my answer on [Alternative to OpenLayers plugin for QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131342/alternative-to-openlayers-plugin-for-qgis) for that.