# how can I speed up openlayers plugin for Google images in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, openlayers-2, google

I use Google aerial photos when using QGIS (2.10.1) using the openlayers plugin.

I find that it is very slow, and often hangs when I refresh or move around the map.

Is there a way of improving its performance - I am certain it is not my internet connection, which is fibre optic.

Comment: In _Settings > Options > Rendering_, there are options to enable **render caching**, utilising **maximum CPU cores** and you can set the **map update interval**. Perhaps play with these options?

Comment: Thank you.  I've just given it a go. Render caching was already set, but I've ticked the multiple cores option.  It hasn't made an obvious improvement.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to add the layer as a raster as described here:

[Alternative to OpenLayers plugin for QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131342/alternative-to-openlayers-plugin-for-qgis/131485#131485)

Or use the quick mapservices plugin:
https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/quick_map_services/

Perhaps loading the layer this way can speed things up.

Answer (score 1):

The projection can make a difference to rendering time. Try setting the map projection to the map tiles' native projection, generally Psuedo Mercator (EPSG:3857).

Comment: This is a very good alternative, and it solved the problem I was having. It also solved another problem I had where Google Maps was rendered with low resolution, probably due to the on-the-fly projection. This is very good indeed.