# Google Maps / StreetView coverage layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, google, google-street-view

I've come across a useful method for adding Google layers as a raster in QGIS: [High resolution, printable alternative to OpenLayers plugin for QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131342/alternative-to-openlayers-plugin-for-qgis/)

Does anyone know what the serverUrl is for the google streetview coverage map? I've found this url but I can't get it to work in the XML:

https://mts1.googleapis.com/vt?hl=en-US&lyrs=svv|cb_client:apiv3&style=40,18&x=9&y=15&z=5

Comment: Keep in mind that Google TOL does not allow to access their imagery other than through their web pages.

Comment: Thank you @AndreJ. We'll be using Google's trekker kit to survey and photograph areas that are not currently on Google StreetView. So the data will very much be used in a 'partnership' with Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the TileLayer plugin for QGIS, and add a line in the tiles.tsv file build from your example URL like this:

```
 Googlesv   Googlesv    https://mts1.googleapis.com/vt?hl=en-US&lyrs=svv|cb_client:apiv3&style=40,18&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}  1   0   20  -180    -85.0   180.0   85.0
```

Note that the file has to be **TAB** delimited. I get this result:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Add this link as a XYZ Tiles layer:

> [https://mts2.google.com/mapslt?lyrs%3Dsvv%26x%3D{x}%26y%3D{y}%26z%3D{z}%26w%3D256%26h%3D256%26hl%3Den&style%3D40,18](https://mts2.google.com/mapslt?lyrs%3Dsvv%26x%3D%7Bx%7D%26y%3D%7By%7D%26z%3D%7Bz%7D%26w%3D256%26h%3D256%26hl%3Den&style%3D40,18)

Comment: quick and easy solution here

Comment: Answer works. What's the official source for this? Interested to read more.

Comment: Probably related: https://community.safe.com/s/question/0D54Q00009o0kMeSAI/read-xyz-tiles