# Rendering tiles using xml files?

Tags: qgis, xml

I'm having trouble displaying some base maps on parts or my organisations network. I set up a QGIS (2.14.9) project and added a couple of layers. I then add a google basemap using 'Thomas B' instructions from here:

[High resolution, printable alternative to OpenLayers plugin for QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131342/high-resolution-printable-alternative-to-openlayers-plugin-for-qgis/131485#131485)

All good.

I took my laptop to work where I have to use a proxy server. OpenLayers and QuickMapServices failed to load until I set the Proxy Server parameters. However, 
the xml files just render as a black background because I think they do not use the proxy settings. They work fine if I'm on the orgnaisation's wireless network.

Assuming I'm correct, is there a way to get the xml files to use the proxy settings?

Comment: You could try using that XML file in gdal to get better diagnostics / see what is really happening. Perhaps your organisation's site is being blocked by google, or by some firewall on your side. There are a lot of options.

Comment: I don't think Google is being blocked as this url returns a tile: http://mt.google.com/vt/lyrs=m@186112443&hl=x-local&src=app&x=1325&y=3143&z=13&s=Galile

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but how would I run the xml through GDAL?

Comment: http://www.gdal.org/frmt_wms.html shows some examples. The XML format **is** a GDAL format (hence the `<GDAL_WMS>` part at the start).

Comment: @BradHards: I'm using a Win10 Laptop and ran gdalinfo (>gdalinfo "WMS:http://mt.google.com/vt/lyrs=m@186112443&hl=x-local&src=app&x=1325&y=3143&z=13&s=Galile"). This returns a 403 error.
The URL in the command returns a tile in IE11. However, if I uncheck the 'use proxy server' in IE>Internet options>connections>LAN Setting then I also get a 403 error.
So I think this somewhat confirms that the issue is that GDAL is not using the proxy settings in QGIS. Is there a way of getting GDAL to use the proxy settings in QGIS Settings>Options>Network?

Comment: Added that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to check this is to isolate the QGIS part from the underlying GDAL part (which is what your XML uses). You can test using a command line, as explained in http://gdal.org/frmt_wms.html, which also explains the general syntax for the XML file.

Based on comments, it does appear that proxy settings are the problem.

GDAL uses the curl library for the HTTP/HTTPS layer, and that respects `http_proxy` environment variable. However you can also specify a `GDAL_HTTP_PROXY` environment variable, along with `GDAL_HTTP_PROXYUSERPWD` and `GDAL_PROXY_AUTH` if you need to authenticate to the proxy.

From https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/ConfigOptions:

> **GDAL_HTTP_PROXY**
>
> Set HTTP proxy to use. The parameter should be the host name or dotted
>   IP address. To specify port number in this string, append :[port] to
>   the end of the host name. The proxy string may be prefixed with
>   [protocol]: since any such prefix will be ignored. The proxy's port
>   number may optionally be specified with the separate option. If not
>   specified, libcurl will default to using port 1080 for proxies.
>
> GDAL respects the environment variables http_proxy, ftp_proxy,
>   all_proxy etc, if any of those are set. GDAL_HTTP_PROXY option does
>   however override any possibly set environment variables.
>
> **GDAL_HTTP_PROXYUSERPWD**
>
> The HTTP user and password to use for the connection to the HTTP
>   proxy. Must be in the form of [user name]:[password].
>
> **GDAL_PROXY_AUTH**
>
> Set value to [BASIC/NTLM/DIGEST/ANY] to tell libcurl which
>   authentication method(s) you want it to use for your proxy
>   authentication. See
>   ​http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTPROXYAUTH
>   for more information

On Windows 10, you can set these variables under Control Panel -> System and Security -> System. Use Advanced System settings and look at the bottom of the "Advanced" tab for "Environment Variables...". Or a web search will probably give you step-by-step instructions - one solution is at https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them

Comment: Thanks @BradHards. Adding these three environment variables worked. :-) I added them as systems variables as user variables didn't seem to work. I did restart QGIS so I'm not sure if that was the difference.